# C# IndexOutOfRangeException even though array size is sufficient

Tags: c#, arrays

```
string[] batsmen_headers = new string[15];

public void Headers()
{
    batsmen_headers[0] = "Player|Mat|Inns|NO|Runs|Best|Average|Bls Fcd|Strike Rt|100s|50s|0s|4s|6s\n";
}
```

I'm writing this code in C#, and I don't understand why but this is showing "IndexOutOfRangeException" error when initializing. Only this array causing problem, other arrays in code working absolutely fine.

Watch here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3TatGg

Comment: You're populating your array in the wrong way string foo[] = new string[]{"0","0","0","0","0"};

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hPtGGr

Comment: Watch here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3TatGg

Comment: Well you declared `teamHeaders` to have 5 elements. Have a look at your code and see how many elements you're trying to put in it.

Comment: Debugger actually pointed at the next line of the code rather than one causing real problem, so it got me troubled. That was great observation from you though, many thanks to you.